# Service-workers blocks backbonejs?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, service-worker

I have built a web app using Backbone.js and it has lots of calls to a RESTful service and it works like a charm.

I tried adding a ServiceWorker to cache all the previous calls so they'll be available offline.

What I actually get is that the calls I do for the first time, dies with this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

However on page reload, I get it's cached data

My service worker fetch:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
// e.respondWidth Responds to the fetch event
e.respondWith(

    // Check in cache for the request being made
    caches.match(e.request)
        .then(function(response) {

            // If the request is in the cache
            if ( response ) {
                console.log("[ServiceWorker] Found in Cache", e.request.url, response);
                // Return the cached version
                return response;
            }

            // If the request is NOT in the cache, fetch and cache

            var requestClone = e.request.clone();
            fetch(requestClone)
                .then(function(response) {

                    if ( !response ) {
                        console.log("[ServiceWorker] No response from fetch ")
                        return response;
                    }

                    var responseClone = response.clone();

                    //  Open the cache
                    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {

                        // Put the fetched response in the cache
                        cache.put(e.request, responseClone);
                        console.log('[ServiceWorker] New Data Cached', e.request.url);

                        // Return the response
                        return response;

                    }); // end caches.open
                    console.log("Response is.. ?", response)
                    return response;

                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Error Fetching & Caching New Data', err);
                });


        }) // end caches.match(e.request)
); // end e.respondWith
});
```

---

edit:
I don't think there is a need for any Backbone.js web app code.
I use the `fetch` method from Backbone.js models and collections.
calls like
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
and 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2

will replay show this error on first time. after refreshing the page, i do have this info without requesting. all from cache.
and all other request that i still didn't do, will stay error

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: I edited: I don't think there is a need for any Backbone.js web app code. I use the fetch method from Backbone.js models and collections. calls like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 and https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2

will replay show this error on first time. after refreshing the page, i do have this info without requesting. all from cache. and all other request that i still didn't do, will stay error

Answer (score 2):

i solved it after searching more.
Backbone.js my views in the Web app used to do:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection,"reset",this.render);
this.listenTo(this.collection,"add",this.addCollectionItem);
this.listenTo(this.collection,"error", this.errorRender);
```

while my Service worker is returning Promises.

I had to change my some code my Web app views to something like this:

```
this.collection.fetch({},{reset:true})
   .then(_.bind(this.render, this))
   .fail(_.bind(this.errorRender,this))
```

more or less...

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that when the request is not in the cache, then you do a `fetch`, but you do not *return* the result of that `fetch` to the enclosing `then` handler. You need to add a `return` so that you have:

```
return fetch(requestClone)
            .then(function(response) {
```

None of the data provided by the `return` statements inside your `then` handler for the `fetch` will get transferred up the chain otherwise.

---

I also see that you do not return the promise provided by `caches.open(cacheName).then...`. This *may* be fine if you want to decouple saving a response in the cache from returning a result up the chain, but at the very least I'd put a comment saying that that's what I'm doing here rather than leave it to the reader to figure out whether a `return` statement is missing by accident, or it was done on purpose.